Cómo evitar el error "No está autorizado para mostrar la declaración de cookies para el dominio"
Estoy utilizando el plugin GDPR Cookie Compliance para gestionar la configuración de las cookies, pero por alguna razón sigo viendo el siguiente script al final de las páginas de Privacidad y Cookies:
Error: El dominio WWW.DOMINIO.COM no está autorizado para mostrar la declaración de cookies para el grupo de dominio con ID xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx. Por favor, añádalo al grupo de dominio en el Cookiebot Manager para autorizar el dominio.
He instalado el plugin Cookiebot Manager y el ID ya está allí, por lo que probablemente la persona anterior que trabajó en el sitio creó una cuenta que ahora ha expirado.
Me gustaría seguir utilizando el GDPR Cookie Compliance.
¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que el script agregue ese texto?
Gracias por cualquier ayuda y disculpen si la pregunta no está muy bien explicada.

Y porqué no haces tu propio banner de Cookies sin plugins y ya??

Gracias. Aunque ya lo he considerado, esa no era mi pregunta.
